# escaped_fragment in sitemap or shebang?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, sitemap, shebang

My site is a Single Page Application and uses alot of javascript. I've got my server setup to generate the site the user sees with javascript so Google sees the same content. Google knows about this via the `fragment` meta tag and converts links with the shebang to `escaped_fragment` to get that rendered site. Since I want Google to know about not-so-recent articles on my site that don't have a link from the mainpage anymore, I added a sitemap.

The question is if I should add urls **with** or **without** the shebang or convert it to escaped_fragment.

http://www.example.com/#!veryAwsomeDynamicPage

or

http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment=veryAwsomeDynamicPage

My Goal: I want Google to get my content via escaped_fragment, but want the link that Google shows in its search result to be with the shebang (so that users don't get redirected)

Comment: Hashbang and escaped fragment is a horrible, horrible hack. We have pushState now, so you really should consider moving to that instead.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the comment. I am using pushState on the client-side for routing, fetching, etc, but I want searchengines to get my page rendered and not an empty html stump. Any Ideas?

Comment: You do something like `pushState("/myURL");` when you use JS to (for example) fill the page with 100 X characters. You then write server side code so that when `/myURL` is requested, the server delivers a page consisting of 100 X characters in the first place.

Comment: hmm... So I guess I'll need to sniff the useragent to determin common search-engine crawlers.. or just output the rendered page to everyone..

Comment: Just output the rendered page to everyone. It gives better performance than loading the homepage and then immediately replacing the it with different content loaded with Ajax.

Comment: as the content is dynamic to the users device-size and local configuration (if he visited prior), it wouldn't make sense to send something the user would need to replace. Google would see outdated but relevant content based on default-settings. Thats why I need no-javascript-friendly pages (searchengines), while the users clicking on search results should get the javascript-friendly page that gets everything dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as outlined in [google's specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) under 'Role of the Search Engine Crawler' it states

`The search engine agrees to display in the search results the corresponding pretty URLs:`

thus, http://www.example.com/#!veryAwsomeDynamicPage is displayed in the search results while google fetches the content on http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment=veryAwsomeDynamicPage

so http://www.example.com/#!veryAwsomeDynamicPage shall be in the sitemap.xml